# Polymer Javascript. couldn't pass data when on-tap event, to other polymer-element without calling the polymer-element

Tags: javascript, listbox, polymer

I have two polymer elements: `<element-a> <element-b>` both of them are child element inside of a parent `<element-c>`, and each of them are on different file.

In `<element-a>`, i have a `<paper-listbox>`, inside there is some `<paper-item>` in there with on-tap event to get the value of it.

the goal is: In the `<element-b>` side, I want to GET from an API with url something like this:

api/configs/{{tempId}}

and call it to a `<p>` in `<element-b>` when a `<paper-listbox>` from `<element-a>` on-tap event is fired.
The {{tempId}} is the value from the selected `<paper-listbox>` from the `<element-a>` side.

I already got the selected `<paper-listbox>` value which i tried printed it on the console, but dunno how to pass it to the `<element-b>` without calling the element. Already tried in some ways like using session storage to set a temporary value for {{tempId}}, but dunno when to call it on the `<element-b>` side. Tried calling it from 'ready: function', didn't work i know. i just tried it to make sure.

Below is some codes for an illustration

```
// element-a.html
    ...
    <paper-listbox selected="0">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{response.data}}">
          <paper-item value="{{item.id}}" on-tap="_getId">
            Configuration ID {{item.id}}
          </paper-item>
        </template>
      </paper-listbox>

<script>
...
_getId: function(e) {
  var tempId = e.path[0].value;
  console.log(e.path[0].value);
}
...
</script>
```

then

```
//element-b.html
<iron-ajax
  ...
  url="api/configs/{{tempId}}"
  ...
  >
```

Any of your help is very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: does your `<element-a>` and `<element-b>` are in a single file?

Comment: sorry i forgot something, the `<element-a>` and `<element-b>` are a child element inside of a parent element lets say `<element-c>` and each are on a different file.

*edited on the question too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the property is in parent element then you can use that in your child elements like this

`<element-b temp-id=[[tempId]]></element-b>`

But in your case you can have a listener in your parent element

```
listeners: {
 'on-tap-listener': '_abc'
}
```

and fire the event in `<element-a>` like this

```
_getId: function(e) {
  var tempId = e.path[0].value;
  console.log(e.path[0].value);
  this.fire('on-tap-listener',tempId);
}
```

Now you have your tempId in your parent element and assign it to a property and bind it to `element-b` as shown above

```
_abc:function(data){
   this.tempId = data.detail.tempId;
},
```

Comment: thank you very much. this works for me with a little edit on last code

`_abc:function(data){
   this.tempId = data.detail;
},`

i can check the {{tempId}} value on the parent element after the on-tap event. but i still dunno if the {{tempId}} value are already passed to `<element-b>` after the on-tap happens. I dunno how to check it on `<element-b>` side.